# Form not submitting inside $.ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm validating for duplicate names by using jquery+Ajax. Everything is working fine except that the form is not submitting once everything returns true

**What's Happening**

- If no name is entered, alert box is showing up stating name is
  required --> No problem here
- If duplicate name is found, alert box is showing up stating name
  already exists and form does not submit --> No problem here
- If duplicate name is not found, alert box is showing up (to prove the
  **`else`** part of the condition is working), but the **form does not
  submit**. I want the form to go ahead and submit itself in this **`else`**
  part

**jQuery Code**

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){

    var name = $('#shelf_name').val();

    if(name == '')
    {
        alert('Shelf name is required');
        $('#shelf_name').focus();
    }
    else
    {                   
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'check-duplicate-shelf-name.php',
            data:{'name':name},
            context:this,
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data == 'stop')
                {
                    alert('Shelf name already exists'); // working if duplicate name is found
                }
                else
                {   
                    alert('else working?'); // alert box is showing up if name is not duplicate                                         
                    this.submit(); // but after alert, this line not executing
                }
            }
        });
    }


    return false;

});
```

**HTML Form Tag**

```
<form action="add-shelf-post.php" method="post" id="form1">
```

**check-duplicate-shelf-name.php** Page

```
<?php

include 'confignew.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];

// peforming database operations
.
.
.

// and then

if($db->num_rows($q) == 0)
{
    echo 'go';
}
else
{
    echo 'stop';
}
```

I'm missing something very obvious. Hopefully someone here can point that out.

After checking with Firebug in Firefox, I indeed got an error. It didn't show up when I was testing with Chrome. Here is the screenshot.

[image: Firebug Error]

Comment: Are you sure 'this' points to where you think it should?

Comment: @JureC. It should point to the form, shouldn't it?

Comment: @asprin don't forget ajax is asynchronous and you are handling the submit event so even if it would correctly submit you would enter the submit event again.

Comment: @asprin I don't think it's the correct one. Just check :)

Comment: @JureC. As I said I haven't been able to figure out what's wrong. If you have spotted it, would you be kind enough to share?

Comment: If you replace `this.submit();` with `$('#form1').submit();`, does it work how you expect it to work?

Comment: If he replaces this.submit(); with $('#form1').submit(); he will probably have a recursive call. The submit event will fire again and again and will never stop.

Comment: @Owlvark I tried that too. But the form refuses to submit, leave alone submitting multiple times

Comment: Oh my goodness. I can't even ask a genuine question in here? I'm not against downvote, but at least give a reason for downvoting the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested your code and it works in Chrome, IE 8 and Mozilla Firefox. Check whether in your whole page there is an element which contains in it's **name attribute** value the word **submit**. If there is rename it. For example an input tag like this: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"/>` will cause the error appeared in your Mozilla Firebug.

Furthermore below you can find an alternative solution.

The following solution has been successfully tested in Chrome, IE 8 and Mozilla Firefox.

**Alternative Solution**

> Retrieve the post URL and the data that you want to post and perform a post in the success callback.

The following implementation has been **successfully tested in Chrome, IE 8 and Mozilla Firefox**. In the success callback, the data to be posted is retrieved and posted to the URL and the result is put to a div with id *result*. You can modify it in order to fit your needs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form1').submit(function(){
        var name = $('#shelf_name').val();
        if(name == '')
        {
            alert('Shelf name is required');
            $('#shelf_name').focus();
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'check-duplicate-shelf-name.php',
                data:{'name':name},
                context:this,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    if(data == 'stop')
                    {
                        alert('Shelf name already exists');
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        alert('else working?'); 
                        //this.submit();
                        //$(this).submit();

                        // get the post url and the data to be posted
                        var $form = $(this);
                            shelfNameVal = $form.find( 'input[id="shelf_name"]' ).val(),
                            url = $form.attr( 'action' );

                            // Send the form data and put the results in the result div
                            $.post(url, { shelf_name: shelfNameVal },
                                function(data) {
                                    $( "#result" ).empty().append(data);
                                }
                            );
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    return false;
    });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The element does have a `name` attribute in it. So no issues there. I see that another function is being run inside `success` which will work, but what I really want to know is why my code isn't working. It used to work before. But suddenly it has stopped working

Comment: Have you tried to debug using Mozilla Firefox Firebug? It would be useful to know if the debugger shows any error. Thanks

Comment: Firebug doesn't show any errors. I'll post the screenshot once I get home. And btw, as mentioned by you above on using `$(this).submit()` is indeed making submit fire indefinitely. It's showing in Firebug.

Comment: Check whether in your whole page there is element which contains in it's **name** attribute the word **submit**. If there is rename it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Tolis. That indeed was the issue. I changed the `name` attribute of the submit button and it worked like a charm. Awarded the bounty to you as well

Answer (score 4):

I would check it with jQuery validator at run time, not on submit but another approach is to make a Rest Style call. I think it's not necessary to POST a full form just to check 1 field.

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){
    //Check not empty
    if(!$('#shelf_name').val()) {
       alert('Shelf name is required');
       $('#shelf_name').focus();
    } else {   
       //Valiate Rest style call             
       $.getJSON("check-duplicate-shelf-name.php/".concat($('#shelf_name').val()), function(data) {
           //If you only have 2 states I would return boolean to faster check ex: if(!data){
           if(data == 'stop') {
               // working if duplicate name is found
               alert('Shelf name already exists'); 
           } else {   
               alert('else working?'); // alert box is showing up if name is not duplicate                                         
               $('#form1').submit(); // but after alert, this line not executing
           }
       });
    }
    return false;
});​
```

When I said on comments that you can post your form manually not using *$(this).submit();* I refer to:

```
$.ajax({
       url: "./myurl",
       cache: false,
       type: "POST",           
       data: $("#form1").serialize(),
       success:  function(){
               console.log("Submit successful");
   }
});
```

Comment: But where is **`this`** referred to in **`$.getJSON`** when I'm using **`this.submit()`** ?

Comment: Sorry man I miss it. **$.getJson** is just a **shorthand for $.ajax** you could make same call with ajax, just change URL and type:'GET'  etc. I modified it using form submit by id.

Comment: Make sure that your controller validation method is correct. The best way is like they said with jQuery.Validation using remote.           If the execution enters the } else {  but doesn't submit you can also submit the form manually. Just using $.ajax and post the form.

Comment: What does this mean `you can also submit the form manually. Just using $.ajax and post the form` Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 3):

Doing remote form validation? Checkout the [`jquery.validate plugin`](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and its [`.remote()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options) rule.

Other than that your code looks fine. Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dKUSb/7/

Comment: I'm trying not to use any plugins. Want to do it using plain jQuery

Comment: The form submits even if I keep the textbox empty in your jsfiddle

Comment: Works for me in IE9, FF and Chrome. What browser are you using? Did you check my latest fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dKUSb/7/

Comment: That is strange. I'm trying it out with your latest fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dKUSb/7/  but still the form is submitting no matter what condition

Comment: Wow, you gotta have some plugin that does something strange. Can you see some errors in the development console?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I checked out the documentation and true/false was what they used. I played with your fiddle and true enough it doesn't work. thanks for noting that in the comment on my answer. You are absolutely right. I will remove my answer as I have no clue then what else could be wrong :) And your fiddle works for me too by the way on latest version of Chrome. +1 for the fiddle and the clarification.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, in your first sentence you say that my fiddle doesn't work and in your last sentence you say that it works. So which is it?

Comment: Let me try your fiddle in Firefox

Comment: Nope. Firefox giving out the same result - Form submitting no matter what

Comment: Nope. Nothing. It's showing the page to which `url` is supposed to go, but no errors shown

Comment: @asprin, I have no idea. Maybe other people could test this script to confirm. But for me it should work. Maybe you could try playing around with it by placing `console.logs` at different places to see what's the problem.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: That is not what I said. I said when I played around with your fiddle applying MY changes to it with true/false it didn't work so you were RIGHT that true/false doesn't work. But trying your fiddle WITHOUT my changes it worked fine! Hope that is clearer now. Trying to tell a guy he is right doesn't seem that easy, enjoy the +1 anyway :)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, that's what you said I quote: `I played with your fiddle and true enough it doesn't work.`. Sorry, English is not my native language and I might have misunderstood this sentence but when I first read it, I was left with the impression that **my** fiddle doesn't work. Anyway, cheers.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I replied in response to you stating my true false does not work. So when I said "I played with your fiddle and true enough it doesn't work " I meant it as confirmation to you being correct. I should have worded it better :) Main thing is, I appreciated your comments regarding the ajax clarification and wanted to let you know that your fiddle is working for me too in Chrome. Good job :)

Comment: @asprin, I think that something is wrong with your system. I've noticed that you left a comment stating that images no longer appear for you on StackOverflow, etc... Did you disable javascript or something? Proxy?

Comment: As far as javascript being disabled, I dont think that is the case because other sections of the code that I pasted are working. For instance, the alert boxes are showing up. Regarding proxy, I'm not sure as I don't know how to determine whether I'm using one or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can benefit from the `callbacks` in this case. Just separate the code like below:

function with the callback that will return an object `{status: 'true or false', message: 'Some text'}`

```
function validity(callback){

    var name = $('#shelf_name').val();

    if(name == '')
    {
        return callback({status: false, message: 'Shelf name is required'});
    }
    else
    {                   
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'check-duplicate-shelf-name.php',
            data:{'name':name},
            context:this,
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data == 'stop')
                {
                     return callback({status: false, message: 'Shelf name already exists'});                    

                }
                else
                {   
                    return callback({status: true, message: 'else working?'});
                }
            }
        });
    }

     //just for safety :))
    return callback({status: false, message: 'something went wrong completely'});
});
```

This returns the result from the AJAX call. It will wait for AJAX to complete and return the corresponding branch result of `if`...

.. and you can now use it as this:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){
    validity(function(result){
       if (result.status) { //status is true
           return true;
       } 
       else
       {
           alert(result.message);
           $('#shelf_name').focus(); 
           return false;      
       }
    });
});
```

... or just combine them like :

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){

        // definition
        function validity(callback){

            var name = $('#shelf_name').val();

            if(name == '')
            {
                return callback({status: false, message: 'Shelf name is required'});
            }
            else
            {                   
                $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url:'check-duplicate-shelf-name.php',
                    data:{'name':name},
                    context:this,
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        if(data == 'stop')
                        {
                             return callback({status: false, message: 'Shelf name already exists'});                    

                        }
                        else
                        {   
                            return callback({status: true, message: 'else working?'});
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

             //just for safety :))
            return callback({status: false, message: 'something went wrong completely'});
        });

        //usage
        validity(function(result){
            if (result.status) { //status is true
                return true;
            } 
            else
            {
                alert(result.message);
                $('#shelf_name').focus(); 
                return false;      
               }
            });
        });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer @alexi but this process turns out to be a bit longer. I was hoping to not make a lot of changes in the existing code

Comment: @asprin, you can include `function validity()` definition within the `$('#form1').submit()` body just before usage of `validity`. It is just a matter of organisation of your code in `$('#form1').submit()` function body.

Answer (score 1):

instead of this.submit() write :

```
document.yourFormName.method = "POST";
document.yourFormName.action = "Relative_URL_to_Go_to";
document.yourFormName.submit();
```

or if you dont know the formName alternately u can use :

```
document.forms[0].method = "POST";
document.forms[0].action = "Relative_URL_to_Go_to";
document.forms[0].submit();
```

Comment: No luck mate from this one too

Answer (score 1):

Completely due to scope

Where you have

```
alert('else working?'); // alert box is showing up if name is not duplicate                                         
this.submit(); // but after alert, this line not executing
```

this is referring to the ajax object, not the form. This is because it is now inside another function.

Im adding `$form = $(this);` before the ajax call to declare a variable you can use inside the callback.

Try this:

```
$('#form1').submit(function( e ){

    e.peventDefault();

    var name = $('#shelf_name').val();

    if(name == '')
    {
        alert('Shelf name is required');
        $('#shelf_name').focus();
    }
    else
    {  
        $form = $(this);         
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'check-duplicate-shelf-name.php',
            data:{'name':name},
            context:this,
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data == 'stop')
                {
                    alert('Shelf name already exists'); // working if duplicate name is found
                }
                else
                {   
                    alert('else working?'); // alert box is showing up if name is not duplicate                                         
                    $form.submit(); // but after alert, this line not executing
                }
            }
        });
    }


    return false;
});
```

**UPDATE:** I may have been completely out of it yesterday. Try adding e.preventDefault(); just above the submit call. Additionally, add the e variable in the function() definition. Check the updated code above.

Here is some documentation on preventDefault(): http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Updated the answer with something new to try.

Comment: Still no luck. The else part inside `success` is working, but the form does not submit

Answer (score 1):

Dont try to much check get simple button and addd onclick event in that  event put the code below

html code

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="formsubmit();">
```

javascript code

```
    function formsubmit() {
     var name = $('#shelf_name').val();

     if (name == '') {
         alert('Shelf name is required');
         $('#shelf_name').focus();
     } else {
         $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url: 'check-duplicate-shelf-name.php',
             data: {
                 'name': name
             },
             context: this,
             success: function (data) {
                 if (data == 'stop') {
                     alert('Shelf name already exists'); // working if duplicate name is found
                 } else {
                     alert('else working?'); // alert box is showing up if name is not duplicate
                     $('#form1').submit()
                 }
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

Comment: No luck with your solution too. Putting an `onclick` event isn't even firing the `formsubmit()` function

Answer (score 1):

The reason the form is not submitting is that you are returning `false` from the `submit` event handler, which causes the default action (submission) to not occur. Even if you call the `submit()` method, you're still within the `submit` event handler, which has returned `false`.

You may want to consider either changing the server-side logic which handles your form submission to also check for duplicates, or attaching the duplicate check ajax post to the `blur` event of the text box, or a submit button as suggested by @rajesh kakawat (except attaching with jQuery rather than an HTML attribute). Example:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){

    var name = $('#shelf_name').val();

    if(name == '')
    {
        alert('Shelf name is required');
        $('#shelf_name').focus();
        return false;
    }
});

$('#shelf_name').on('blur', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        name = $this.val();
    if(name == '')
    {
        alert('Shelf name is required');
        $this.focus();
        return false;
    }

        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'check-duplicate-shelf-name.php',
            data:{'name':name},
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data == 'stop')
                {
                    alert('Shelf name already exists'); // working if duplicate name is found
                }
                else
                {   
                    alert('else working?'); // alert box is showing up if name is not duplicate                                         
                    $('#form1').submit(); // this should work now
                }
            }
        });
});
```

I'm not sure why the `this.submit();` line was working previously, as I don't know enough about your application, script version, etc.. You may want to consider using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to post an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){

    var name = $('#shelf_name').val();

    if(name == '')
    {
        alert('Shelf name is required');
        $('#shelf_name').focus();
    }
    else
    {                   
        var istrue = false;        
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'check-duplicate-shelf-name.php',
            data:{'name':name},
            context:this,
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data == 'stop')
                {
                    alert('Shelf name already exists');
                    istrue = false;
                }
                else
                {   
                    alert('else working?') // alert box is showing up                           
                    istrue = true;
                }
            }
        });
        return istrue;
    }
});
```

some thing like this :)
cant test

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and think we sorted out.

The thing is that the `.submit()` action doesn't work inside the "thread" `$.ajax` neither `$.post`.
For that you have to add the `async:false` instruction inside the `$.ajax` block and submit the form when the `$.ajax` execution finishes.

Not tested but this is the working idea:

**html:**

```
<input type='submit' onClick='javascript:MyCheck(); return false;'>
```

**javacript:**

```
function Mycheck() {

   var result = "";
   $.ajax {
       async:false,
       url: you_url_here,
       timeout: 15000,
       success: function(data) {
            result="success";
       },
       error: function(request, status, err) {
            result="error";
       }
   };

   // Here, if success -> SUBMIT FORM or whatever
   // Only get here if "ASYNC" = FALSE!!!
   if (result == "success") {
       $("form").submit(); // this submits the form
       return;
   } else {
       alert('error');
       // the form will not be post
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is one of the few occasions when `async` might be justified. It would be better, however, to bind the event handler in a jQuery-ish fashion, rather than with inline Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the update Samuel, but as seen above I've already sorted out the issue

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy it's Working..

```
document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.formname);
```