# Ajax return false to form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

Hi I'm looking to check my database when a user signs up to my website to make sure that the username they chose doesn't already exist and if it does let them know. My code below isn't working though the returns in the ajax don't seem to be returned to my form no matter what i do and the form always submits. Why is this happening? Thank you for any help

**HTML**

```
<form name="signup" action="Test1.php" onsubmit="return checkUser();" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"/></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkUser(){
        var userV = document.signup.user.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "Test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {user:userV},
            success: function (response) {
                if(response=="0"){
                    //Username already exists notify user
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Test.php**

```
<?PHP
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    if($user=="test"){
        die("0");
    }else{
        die("1")
    }
?>
```

**Test1.php**

```
<?PHP
    echo "Form submitted";
?>
```

Comment: I'm facing a very similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017823/form-not-submitting-inside-ajax-success-function   See if any answer in there can help you

Comment: The number one JavaScript question. Why my asynchronous call does not work synchronously.

Comment: Try removing the "return" from the onsubmit. Wild guess. Going back to looking at your code :P

Comment: Also, you don't need to use die as far as my experience goes unless you want the page to code to halt and dump the variables. Just use echo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the `return` value inside the `success` callback of your ajax call, whose execution is delayed till server answers.

`onsubmit="return checkUser();"` expects a `true` or `false` value in `checkUser()` function:

```
function checkUser(){

   if( stuff )
      return true;
   else
      return false;

}
```

Anyway this is an overall bad approach because it relies on intrusive javascript. A better solution would be moving all client side logic out of markup:

**HTML**

```
<form name="signup" action="Test1.php" method="get">
    <label for="_user">Username:</label><input type="text" name="user" id="_user"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
// wrapping the code in a $(function(){ ... }); call delays its execution till document is loaded
$(function(){

$('form[name="signup"]').on('submit', function(event){

    // this prevents browser from actually following form url
    event.preventDefault();

    // a reference to the form to get used inside ajax callback
    var form = this;

    $.ajax({
         url: $(form).attr('action'),
         type: "POST",
         data: {user:$(form.user).val()},
         success: function (response) {
             if(response=="0"){

                alert('User exists!');

             }else{

                alert('User does not exist!');

             }
         }
     });

});

});
</script>
```

Where the alerts would be a proper message to the user, or a more sophisticate validation - this is just for example's sake.

Comment: sorry i'm new to this :) and this is probably a dumb question but the JS you provided should i put that in the <head></head> and inside of <script type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Don't put JS into `<head>`, but at the very end of `<body>` tag [before closing it]: this speeds up page load. See my edit.

Comment: not sure why but when i put the ajax there nothing in success runs however if i comment that out and put an alert in place of it, it does run. I have the <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"/></script> line in my head tags still so that ajax should run but it's not working for some reason sorry for being such a pain

Comment: turns out i was missing a ; in Test.php after the second die lol finally just found that code works perfectly! Up vote and an accept! Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

You return `false` in the callback, thats too "late", as it will be called when the request is done. Think about adding an explicit `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` to your function. Currently, it will return `undefined`, as you have defined the `return` statement in the "inner" function.

Of course you will then need to manually navigate to the target page.

Or set the `async` [parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) of the `$.ajax()` call explictly to `false`.