# preventing form submision and submiting form on success function ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have problem with submiting the form in success .,.. function? in ajax
It just doesn't work.
code:

```
$("#settings_submit_button").on('click',function(evt){
    var settings_email = $("#settings_new_email").val();
    var current_password = $("#current_password").val();
evt.preventDefault();
    if($("#settings_current_email").val() != '')
    {
        if(ValidateEmail($("#settings_new_email").val()))
        {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'AjaxChecker.php',
            data: {settings_email :settings_email, current_password: current_password},
            success: function(data)
            {
                var response = $.trim(data);
                if(response == 'notright')
                {
                 $("#settings_loader2").text("zadali ste nesprávne heslo");
                }
                else if(response == 'taken')
                {
                  $("#settings_loader2").text("email je obsadený");
                }
                else
                {
                $("#settings_loader2").empty();
                 $("#1").submit();
                }
            }
        });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#settings_loader2").text("email je v nesprávnom tvare");
        }
    }
});
```

I have same issue as this guy

[Form not submitting inside $.ajax success function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017823/form-not-submitting-inside-ajax-success-function)

1 -> the ID of the form

$("#settings_loader2").empty(); -> works

$("#1").submit(); -> this does not work

What this does is that this shit checkes if email is taken or not right format  using ajax . Code checked also on www.jshint.com .-.. contains no errors

Answer (score 1):

Using ID's like integers it's not a good way to have, anyway you should check the id at your form to have the same as submit call.

Please share the HTML also for future help, right now your code seems to be ok.

- Do proper verifications in 'AjaxChecker.php' POST on the PHP side so you don't use var injects as real data.